# How to not display single child row in ag-grid group row?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

If a group row has only 1 child, it may be redundant to show the child row.
Is there a way to hide single child row in a grouped ag-grid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes! Ag-Grid provides this feature. Just set **groupRemoveSingleChildren=true** in your grid options.
This removes groups from display if they only have one child.

Official docs here - https://ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grouping-single-group-column/#removing-single-children

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to use it for SSRM too?